# PHP/Laravel search query controller

Tags: php, laravel, search

I am trying to build a search query to use the user's search input (gene name) and return the gene location and symbol from a JSON file I loaded in.

My Site Controller for the JSON input:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SiteController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $results = file_get_contents("http://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/genenames/hgnc/json/locus_groups/protein-coding_gene.json");
        $data = json_decode($results, true);
        dd($data);
    }
}
```

My Search Controller for the search function:

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SearchController extends Controller
{
    public function search(Request $request){
    // Get the search value from the request
    $search = $request->input('search');

    // Search in the name column from the data table
    $data = data::query()
        ->where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
        ->get();

    // Return the search view with the results compacted
    return view('search', compact('data'));
    }
}
```

My routes:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
//use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Controllers\SiteController;

Route::get('/data', [SiteController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('search', [SearchController::class, 'search']);
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

And my welcomeblade:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Geisinger</title>

       <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1866062af8.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

             <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('/styles.css') }}" >
    </head>

 <body>
     <img src="{{ asset('/Geisinger_logo.jpg') }}" alt="Geisinger Logo">
    <h1> Geisinger Gene Search </h1>

     <div class="container my-8 py-5 px-5 mx-5">
    <!-- Search input -->
    <form action="{{ route('search') }}" method="GET">>
        <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Gene Name" name="search">
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
    <div class="d-grid gap-2 col-6 mx-auto">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-dark" type="button">Search <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i></button>
</div>
<br>
<br>

<h2>Results <i class="fa-solid fa-square-poll-horizontal"></i></h2>
    <!-- List items -->
   <?php
    @if($data->isNotEmpty())
    @foreach ($data as $data)
        <ul class="list-group mt-3">
        <li class="list-group-item">{{ $data->name }}<</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">{{ $data->location }}</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">{{ $data->symbol }}</li>
    </ul>
    @endforeach
@else 
    <div>
        <h2>No Gene found</h2>
    </div>
@endif
   ?> 



    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I keep getting "route 'search' not defined" and "syntax error unexpected token "if"". Thank you for your help!

Comment: In your SearchController, from where did you get this **data** field in this statement `data::query() ->where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%") ->get(); `. You need to specify a Model name in place of **data** that is pointing to the "data" table.

Answer (score 0):

You can only access the `route()` method on named routes. In your `web.php` file, you must give your search route the name `search` before you can access it via `route('search')`

In you `web.php` change:

```
Route::get('search', [SearchController::class, 'search']);
```

to this:

```
Route::get('search', [SearchController::class, 'search'])->name('search');
```

Please visit [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/urls#urls-for-named-routes) to learn more.

Comment: Thank you! Now it's giving me the error "Undefined variable $data" in the welcome blade near the if statement. I removed the php tag but maybe I need that before this section? <h2>Results <i class="fa-solid fa-square-poll-horizontal"></i></h2>

Comment: @NicoleJaffke you are not passing any data to the welcome view ... where is `$data` supposed to come from?

Comment: @NicoleJaffke You need to pass a variable to your view file this way ```return view('welcome', compact('data'));```

Comment: I placed that code in my routes under the first route (is that the correct spot for it?). It's giving me the error "compact(): Undefined variable $data" from the routes page now.

Comment: That is because you did not define the ```$data``` variable in that place.

Comment: I have that code already in the search controller also. Do I not need it in the routes then?

Comment: I'm quite a bit lost at what you are trying to achieve. You can email me from my profile, so I can see more portions of your code if you wish.